# Hide DIV if it has a P with specific text

Tags: javascript

Looking for some help, I'm trying to hide a DIV if it contains a P with a specific text or class, which ever is easier.

Here is as far as I've got, I'm able to hide the P but I need to hide the whole div with the class of "upcoming-events" so the H3 dosen't show.

**The one catch I have is that it can't be jquery, pure Javascript.**

Thanks!

```js
let filteredOut = ['Carousel contents not found!'];

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.upcoming-events p")).forEach((elm) => {
 if(filteredOut.includes(elm.textContent.trim())) {
   elm.style.display = "none";
 }
})
```

```css
#carousel-97826 .slick-prev:before, #carousel-97826 .slick-next:before {
     color: !important;
}
 #carousel-97826 .slick-slide {
     margin: 2px ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-title {
     color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-content {
     color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-date {
     background-color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-date {
     color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-overlay {
     background-color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .carousel-style9 {
     border-top-color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .carousel-style9 .button:before {
     background-color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-box {
     box-shadow: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-bg {
     background-color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-title-bg {
     background-color: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .fixed-height-image {
     height: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .slick-next:before {
     content: '\ \f0a9 ';
}
 #carousel-97826 .slick-prev:before {
     content: '\ \f0a8';
}
#carousel-97826 .rpc-title {
     font-family: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-title {
     font-size: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-content {
     font-family: ;
}
 #carousel-97826 .rpc-content {
     font-size: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="upcoming-events" style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">Highlighted Events</h3>
  <p>Carousel contents not found!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) usually has a parent, hence the properties `parentNode` / `parentElement`

Comment: probably what you need is: `elm.parentNode.style.display='none'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML DOM parentNode Property inside if condition.

```
elm.parentNode.style.visibility = "hidden";
```